# Create a recurring event on FullCalendar plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar but I need create a recurring event, that happen forever(e.g. an event that happens weekly), there is some feature for this? If it not have, how can I implement it?

Comment: Try adding more tags next time you ask a question, like `jQuery`. Did you try not specifying an end date?

Comment: Yes, but it creat a event for allday, and no a recursive event.

Comment: Make the end date 01/01/2500 then, it seems as if it goes forever (and no one will be able to tell you wrong, since you'll be dead ^^)

Comment: The problem is I need to creat an event for each day, than I need to create at least a hundred events for this, and it will consume a lot of processing, because when the browser will render the calendar, it will process all events I creat.

Comment: I'm about to try this using asp.net mvc. I plan to create a linq to entities query which returns an event contingent on a datetime parameter, then addMonth(1) or addWeek(1) etc. I'm not sure how it will work yet, I'll comment back if I have any luck!

Answer (score 3):

If two or more events in fullcalendar have the same id they're treated as one just as the example "Repeating event" in http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ so, you can send the plugin something like this from PHP

```
echo json_encode(array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'test',
            'start' => strtotime('now')
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'test',
            'start' => strtotime('+1 weeks')
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'test',
            'start' => strtotime('+2 weeks')
        ),
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'test',
            'start' => strtotime('+3 weeks')
        )
    ));
```

You can use a javascript helper to transform the array into json if you're using some sort of phpframework such as CakePHP.

In case you are not using some server side processing you can code the events by yourself directly form javascript. Json events should look like this:

```
[{"id":1,"title":"test","start":1324426610},{"id":1,"title":"test","start":1325031410},{"id":1,"title":"test","start":1325636210},{"id":1,"title":"test","start":1326241010}]
```

Note: start and end dates format can be other such as "2011-12-20 12:20:23" (string in this case) or something like that (Unix timestamps are used in my example).